# Whats the best way to switch form in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

So in the project I'm planning, the user will be switching between different screens frequently. These different screens will have different controls with different functions, and really nothing in common.

Should I create a form for each screen and just form.close and form.show(?) to switch screen? Or is it better to keep hiding and showing certain controls, so if a user wants to go to form B from form A, all of form A's controls disappear, and form Bs controls appear? I don't need to know how to do it, I just need to know which is the recommended or proper way, since I haven't really seen it anywhere.

Comment: I would suggest you separate each "view" to its own form as then the logic to display each form will be separate and simpler.

Comment: I would keep just ONE FORM that acts as a container for all the rest.  Develop the other "forms" as UserControls.  Declare all the UserControls at Form level and then you can simply switch what UserControl is currently docked and displayed inside the main Form...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use

```
form.close();
```

as this will close the current form (and if its your main form, exit the application) use

```
form.hide();
```

instead. An example is given below

from Form1:

```
private void btnModify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Form mod = new modifyForm();
mod.Owner = this;
mod.Show();
this.Hide();
}//end btnModify_Click
```

from modifyForm:

```
private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Owner.Show();
    this.Close();

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll play around with your examples and see if I can make sense of them, I'm still very new to C#.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try using the TabControl. You can group your different screens into the different tab items. All you have to do is drag it to the form and edit its content in the Properties window.